# How to write in different line in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to save in a .txt two lineEdit but in different line. It is together on the same line.

```
if(sFile.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text))
    {
        QTextStream out(&sFile);

        out << ui.lineEdit_2->text();
        out << ui.lineEdit->text();

        sFile.flush();
        sFile.close();
    }
```

PD: The text I'm putting in Qt Designer with LineEdit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `endl` or `"\n"` (n for "new line"). This is not Qt specific, but C++ in general:

```
out << ui.lineEdit_2->text() << "\n" 
    << ui.lineEdit->text();
```